# What MongoDB user role can make POST calls?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, nginx, privileges

I just have created a **MongoDB** instance on **Ubuntu 14.04**, with authentication by `username:password.`
The user I've created is like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "myDatabase.myUser",
  "user" : "myUser",
  "db" : "myDatabase",
  "roles" : [ { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "myDatabase" } ]
}
```

And the URI String that I use on my REST API written in **Node.js** (with Express and Mongoose) is like:

```
mongodb://myUser:password@localhost:27017/myDatabase
```

The Connection is OK and the `GET` methods works fine, but when I use a `POST` method, like a signup by email/password, the response is:

```
Status Code:405 Not Allowed
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

**FYI**: I'm using Nginx as reverse proxy and Web Server for the Frontend (AngularJS app), and the config is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

  location / {
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    root /usr/share/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /api/v1 {
    proxy_set_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    proxy_set_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE";
    proxy_set_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin";

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1;
    proxy_buffering on;

    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    origin      "http://example.com";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it isn't a mongodb restriction. Mongo can't know if the request is POST or GET. Have you verified if the request arrives at nodejs server? I think that nginx is who returns the 405 status code.

It's possible that the failure is due to try to **return a static page as response to the POST** request. Try adding into nginx.conf file:

```
  # To dispatch static pages on POST request
  error_page 405 = 200 $uri;
```

Comment: Thank you @Jose! I tried this but not worked yet.
I add the follow: `proxy_redirect off;` and works!

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following and nginx at least works!:

`proxy_redirect off;`

The nginx config for default now is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

 location / {
   expires -1;
   add_header Pragma "no-cache";
   add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
   root /usr/share/www;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
 }

 location /api/v1 {
      proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http:/example.com';
      proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
      proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering on;

      proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    origin      "http://example.com";
   }
}
```

I hope this be valid for somebody.